# Induced metric on symmetric group

Tags: metric-spaces, symmetric-groups

Every metric $d$ on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ induces a metric

$D(a,b) := \sum_{i=1}^{n} d(a(i),b(i))$
on the symmetric group $S_n$.

Is this induced metric right or left invariant or both?

Left invariance: $D(c \cdot a, c \cdot b) = D(a,b) $ for all $a,b,c \in S_n$

Right invariance: $D(a \cdot c, b \cdot c) = D(a,b) $ for all $a,b,c \in S_n$

Multiplication: $c := a\cdot b$ is defined as $c(i) = a(b(i))$ for all $i$.

Comment: Right invariance is obvious. Left invariance does not hold as you can determine for yourself using $n=3$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was not sure about the left invariance.